# How add Tycho packaging types into maven dialogs in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e, tycho

I have only `jar`, `pom` and `war` options in `Packaging` drop down list of `Create new POM` dialog when converting project to `Maven`.

[image]

Simultaneously, it is said for Tycho design, that it should be set for `eclipse-plugin`. If I enter this value explicitly, I get `Unknown packaging type` error message.

Is it possible to add Tycho packaging types into Eclipse dialogs?

Comment: Yes, but probably not without changing the m2e or m2e Tycho connector code. If you want to contribute this code change, the [m2e-dev mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/m2e-dev) may be a good starting point to discuss this.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of choosing ready option, just write "eclipse-plugin" in packaging field. It should work.

Comment: The question says "If I enter this value explicitly, I get Unknown packaging type error message.", so manually typing it in does not work.

Comment: Yes, it does work. But afterwards, you still need to manually ensure that the Tycho build extension is configured. Really, the question is unclear: does the OP want to just use the wizard, or does he want to make it more useful for Tycho projects?